# Using c-python APIs to run Python code in CPP code in some thread

Tags: c++, cpython

I am using c-python apis to run some python code inside my cpp project. Everything is working all fine but suddenly I got one major issue that needs to be rectified.

I have this function that calls Python code inside it in some infinite loop.

```
void runPython(){
    // init python module
    // load module
    // load function
    while(1){
        // create list using c-python api
        // populate input
        // call python function using c-python APIs
        // get output and free up the references
    }

}
```

So this scenario is working perfect. I have no memory leaks and it is able to run as long as I want.
But then I changed some structure like this-
I created a thread using std::thread and then assign this runPython() with this thread and run it. But after this, my python code executes in some half of the way and then I don't know where the thread goes. It stops executing the python code and never returns back to runPython thread anymore. If I have some other parallel threads running then  that thread is running fine.
I tried to use std::thread and pthread both as in pthread I tried to increase the stack size of this thread to around 1000mb but the issue is same.

Any idea what may be the cause?

Point : I have 7-8 big lists of float32 of size 100000 each that I am passing into python function.

https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html

Comment: please post a [mcve] of the non working code rather than only the code that works perfectly

Comment: Sure. Let me edit

Comment: Actually, the issue is not in some minimal code. I have some complex computation going on and I think because of this it is happening. As of now I am not able to give minimal error prone code. Will try to post once get chance. Thanks